# How do I write a spec for a DeleteWhere method?

Tags: c#, mspec

I need to write a spec, for code coverage purposes, for one of our services. The method in question is:

```
public void RemoveOpenMortgageLoanAccount(int accountNumber)
{
    using (var db = this.dbFactory.NewDb().InAppContext())
    {
        db.DeleteWhere<OpenMortgageLoanAccountsDataModel>(string.Format("AccountKey = {0}", accountNumber));
        db.Complete();
    }
}
```

I tried a few things, but I can't make sense of this. It would be something like the example below, but I can't get the syntax right.

```
It should_remove_the_correct_mkortgage_loan_account = () =>
{
    fakeDb.FakedDb
        .InAppContext()
        .WasToldTo(x => x.DeleteWhere<OpenMortgageLoanAccountsDataModel>(y => y.accountKey == accountKey));
};
```

Comment: What db framework are you using, which I assume is providing the `DeleteWhere` method. And what fake/assertion library are you using that's providing the `WasToldTo` method?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing tests for "code coverage" purposes. You should be writing tests to verify business logic. Your current test even if it works, is testing implementation details...which tests shouldn't be coupled to

Comment: When i say coverage, i mean that these will continuously run on our build server against our code base. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, Machine.Specifications framework, the WasToldTo method is provided by the Machine.Fakes library.